# Show function fails on DataFrame, with exception-> Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.lang.Object on MapPartition's return Object

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

I got below Excetion, While printing data of Dataframe returned from mapPartitions,

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.lang.Object
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: java.lang.Object, value: java.lang.Object@382eb59a)
    - field (class: sql.MapPartitions$$anonfun$1, name: nonLocalReturnKey1$1, type: class java.lang.Object)
    - object (class sql.MapPartitions$$anonfun$1, <function1>)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.MapPartitionsExec, name: func, type: interface scala.Function1)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.MapPartitionsExec, MapPartitions <function1>, obj#22: org.apache.spark.sql.Row
+- DeserializeToObject createexternalrow(_c0#10.toString, _c1#11.toString, _c2#12.toString, _c3#13.toString, StructField(_c0,StringType,true), StructField(_c1,StringType,true), StructField(_c2,StringType,true), StructField(_c3,StringType,true)), obj#21: org.apache.spark.sql.Row
   +- *(1) FileScan csv [_c0#10,_c1#11,_c2#12,_c3#13] Batched: false, Format: CSV, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:/C:/Users/Vikas Singh/Documents/Vikas/Study/Spark Material/spark/sample_fi..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<_c0:string,_c1:string,_c2:string,_c3:string>
)
```

Following is the code sippnet:

```
val dataDF = spark.read.format("csv")
  .option("header", "false")
  .load("dataFile.csv")

val schema = StructType(Seq(
  StructField("year", StringType),
  StructField("make", StringType),
  StructField("model", StringType)
))
val encoder = RowEncoder(schema)
val transformed = lines.mapPartitions(partiotion => {
  val recMapPartitions = partiotion.map(rec => {
    rec.getAs(1)
  })

  return recMapPartitions
})(encoder)

transformed.show()
```

Could you please help!!

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Also, `schema ` does not seem to be used anywhere.

Comment: I forgot to past,encoder creation line, Now I have added it

Comment: It looks a bit like you are trying to do something simple in a complicated way. What is your expected output?